# How escape html in echo of javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I can't  escape my code JS in my echo :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    // Initialiser l'objet.
    var tab_nb_match_par_user = ".json_encode($tab_nb_match_par_user).";
    var taille = 70;    
    console.log(tab_nb_match_par_user);
    for (var k in tab_nb_match_par_user){
        $('#img').append('<img src="stats_matching/' + k + '.gif" alt="' + k + '" title="' + k + '" width="' + taille + '" />');
        taille = taille-6;
    }
</scrip>";
```

And I have this follow error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: You are missing a "t" in your </script> end tag.

Comment: And you seem to have some wrong quotes there. If you want to use double quote ( " ) in your javascript you have to escape them like \"

Comment: thanks @Gunni , I found my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the code using a back slash:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

                        // Initialiser l'objet.
                        var tab_nb_match_par_user = ".json_encode($tab_nb_match_par_user).";
                        var taille = 70;    
                        console.log(tab_nb_match_par_user);
                        for (var k in tab_nb_match_par_user){
                            $('#img').append('<img src=\"stats_matching/' + k + '.gif\" alt=\"' + k + '\" title=\"' + k + '\" width=\"' + taille + '\" />');
                            taille = taille-6;
                        }
                </scrip>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use HEREDOC instead of echo.

```
echo <<<ENDOFSCRIPT
<script type='text/javascript'>

                    // Initialiser l'objet.
                    var tab_nb_match_par_user = ".json_encode($tab_nb_match_par_user).";
                    var taille = 70;    
                    console.log(tab_nb_match_par_user);
                    for (var k in tab_nb_match_par_user){
                        $('#img').append('<img src="stats_matching/' + k + '.gif" alt="' + k + '" title="' + k + '" width="' + taille + '" />');
                        taille = taille-6;
                    }
            </script>

ENDOFSCRIPT;
```

more info at https://wiki.php.net/rfc/heredoc-with-double-quotes

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you only want to actually have php fill in the json part, why not just echo in the bit you need, rather than the whole structure. This is **much** better practice in templating.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // Initialiser l'objet.
    var tab_nb_match_par_user = "<?php echo json_encode($tab_nb_match_par_user) ?>";
    var taille = 70;    
    console.log(tab_nb_match_par_user);
    for (var k in tab_nb_match_par_user){
        $('#img').append('<img src="stats_matching/' + k + '.gif" alt="' + k + '" title="' + k + '" width="' + taille + '" />');
        taille = taille-6;
    }
 </script>
```

you were also missing a 't' in your end script tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo <<<END
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialiser l'objet.
        var tab_nb_match_par_user = ".json_encode($tab_nb_match_par_user).";
        var taille = 70;    
        console.log(tab_nb_match_par_user);
        for (var k in tab_nb_match_par_user){
            $('#img').append('<img src="stats_matching/' + k + '.gif" alt="' + k + '" title="' + k + '" width="' + taille + '" />');
            taille = taille-6;
        }
    </script>
END;
```